# Loop over RetrieveSalesforceObject to find a record not opted out

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, contact

It's my first time posting here so forgive me if it's not following the community's standards.

I'm looping over the Contact Salesforce Object, that in case more than one record with the same email address, find the one that is not opted out. In case all of them are opted out, I want to re-subscribe the most recent record. I'm kinda stuck in AMPscript. This is what I have so far:

```
%%[
SET @emailAddress = 'test1@gmail.com'
SET @existingContact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id, HasOptedOutOfEmail, CreatedDate', 'Email', '=', @emailAddress)
SET @rowCountExistingContact = RowCount(@existingContact)
SET @counter = 0

IF @rowCountExistingContact > 0 THEN
   SET @contactFound = 'False'
       FOR @i = @rowCountExistingContact DOWNTO 1 DO
           IF @contactFound == 'False' THEN
               SET @contactRow = Row(@existingContact, @i)
               SET @subscriberKey = Field(@contactRow, 'Id')
               SET @optedOut = Field(@contactRow, 'HasOptedOutOfEmail')

               /* the first record is false break the loop */
               IF @optedOut == 'False' THEN 
                  SET @contactFound = 'True' 
                  SET @mostRecentSubKey = @subscriberKey

               /* if not continue the loop until find a false value */
               ELSE 
                  IF @optedOut != 'False' AND @counter < @rowCountExistingContact THEN
                     SET @counter = Add(@counter, 1)                    
                  ENDIF
               ENDIF
         NEXT @i
ENDIF
]%%
```

The problem here is when the loop is over it will select the last record that will be the oldest one.
I'm unable to think how I can grab the most recent record in case all of them are true. That would be the first iteration in the loop. I was thinking perhaps storing in a variable. Could anyone help me with an approach to this problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You should add two variables: createdDate and recordId. For each record iteration, you will compare the createdDate to the one from that particular record if it is newer, you will update the date and recordId and skip to next record. If not: skip to next record. This way, you will end up with record ID of the newest contact.

Comment: @LukasLunow thanks for your comment! Do you mean in the ELSE statement? recordId will not be @subscriberKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but I will recommend you doing following logic:

1. Iterate through all the records
2. If the record is opted in, use the ID as subscriber key
3. If the record is opted out, store the ID and the createdDate
4. Try next record, unless opted in record is found
5. If this opted out record has a newer created date, overwrite ID with it's ID
6. Finally, if no opted in records are found, set HasOptedOutOfEmail to false for the ID with latest createdDate

```ampscript
%%[
VAR @createdDate, @recordId, @subscriberKey, @optedOutId
SET @emailAddress = 'test1@gmail.com'
SET @existingContact = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'Id, HasOptedOutOfEmail, CreatedDate, Id', 'Email', '=', @emailAddress)
SET @rowCountExistingContact = RowCount(@existingContact)
SET @counter = 0

IF @rowCountExistingContact > 0 THEN
   SET @contactFound = 'False'
       FOR @i = @rowCountExistingContact DOWNTO 1 DO
           IF @contactFound == 'False' THEN
               SET @contactRow = Row(@existingContact, @i)
               SET @recordId = Field(@contactRow, 'Id')
               SET @createdDate = Field(@contactRow, 'createdDate')
               SET @optedOut = Field(@contactRow, 'HasOptedOutOfEmail')

               /* the first record is false break the loop */
               IF @optedOut == 'False' THEN 
                      SET @subscriberKey = @recordId
                      SET @contactFound = 'True' 
               ELSE
                  IF @createdDateRow > @createdDate THEN
                      SET @createdDate = @createdDateRow
                      SET @optedOutId = @recordId
                  ENDIF
               ENDIF
         NEXT @i

    IF @contactFound == 'False' THEN
      set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
          "Contact", @optedOutId,
          "HasOptedOutOfEmail", 'False'
      )
    ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: thanks @LukasLunow now I understood. Let me try here. Thanks for the insights!